# How to extend generic class returning generic value in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, stack, extension-methods

I've having a problem extending the generic Stack class with a simple Clone method. This my approach:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stack<string> myStack = new Stack<string>();
        myStack.Push("hello!");

        var stackClone = myStack.Clone();

    }
}

public static class StackMixin<T>
{
    public static Stack<T> Clone<T>(this Stack<T> stackToClone)
    {
        if (stackToClone == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        IEnumerable<T> reversedStackToClone = stackToClone.Reverse<T>();
        Stack<T> cloneStack = new Stack<T>(reversedStackToClone);
        return cloneStack;
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> `System.Collections.Generic.Stack<string>` does not contain a
>   definition for '`Clone`'   and no extension method '`Clone`' accepting
>   a first argument of type `System.Collections.Generic.Stack<string>`
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I've been googling for the solution or the explenation, but has ended up with no luck. (This is what I've: tried 
https://www.google.pl/#q=generic+extension+method+c%23)

Comment: change `public static class StackMixin<T>` to `public static class StackMixin`

Comment: I didn't hit on that... thanks!

Comment: @IlyaBursov - You should put your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments: change `public static class StackMixin<T>` to `public static class StackMixin`